# Tikzpicture with caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

How I do a caption in Tikz? e.g.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\caption{Cuadrado}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

is an error.

Answer (score 11):

A `caption` is a thing you attach to a `figure`; a `tikzpicture` is like an image, or a block of text, or whatever you want to put *into* a picture.

Try:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Un cuadrado}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Okay thanks but, does it work in class `article` and `book`?

Comment: ...have you tried? ;-)

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but in class `book` there are two errors, "Not in outer par mode" and "Undefined control sequence"

Comment: If you insert code provided in @Rmano answer., mentioned erors cannot happen.

Comment: @luis.pga please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the errors and post it, better if in another question. The problem in posting snippets, as you did, is that it's impossible to know what packages and options you have --- my cristall ball is broken and I can go out to repair it... ;-)

Comment: @luis.pga I can reproduce your errors if I wrap the above code into `$...$`. The above answer is correct, wrapping the code in a math environment is not.

Comment: In more detail, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Un cuadrado}
\end{figure}
$
\end{document}` reproduces the error messages, but this is not the fault of the answer here, rather, it is because of an incorrect usage.

Comment: Okay guys, forget it, I had an error in my code, your solution is correct, Thanks and sorry for bothering you.!

Answer (score 5):

To be clear, [Rmano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536039/194703) is the way to go in almost all realistic cases. However, exceptionally there can be good reasons to just add a caption to some `tikzpicture`, e.g. when you arrange them in a tabular. In this case you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{caption/.style={insert path={
let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$) in
(current bounding box.south) node[below,text width=\x1-4pt,align=center] 
{\captionof{figure}{#1}}}}}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\path[caption=Cuadrado];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can define a style that automatically puts the caption at the end of the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{caption/.style={execute at end picture={\path
let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$) in
(current bounding box.south) node[below,text width=\x1-4pt,align=center] 
{\captionof{figure}{#1}};}}}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[caption=Cuadrado]
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm new in Tikz and I don't know several functions in this code, but it's of great help. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, nice, +1 - - - that execute at end picture is a nice thing to know!

Comment: @Rmano This is a nice trick that allows one to "hack" environments that use a `tikzpicture` environment such as `tikzcd` or `smartdiagram`. "Hack" is not meant to be negative here, it just means "customize".

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @luis.pga You're welcome!

Comment: How do you label and reference this tikzpicture?